# Customer Error: Additional hyperparameters are not allowed - Image classification training- Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, classification, amazon-sagemaker

I'm learning image classification with Amazon SageMaker. I was trying to follow their  learning demo **Image classification transfer learning demo** (`Image-classification-transfer-learning-highlevel.ipynb`)

I got up to Start the training. Executed below.

```
ic.fit(inputs=data_channels, logs=True)
```

Set the hyper parameters as given in the demo

```
ic.set_hyperparameters(num_layers=18,
                             use_pretrained_model=1,
                             image_shape = "3,224,224",
                             num_classes=257,
                             num_training_samples=15420,
                             mini_batch_size=128,
                             epochs=1,
                             learning_rate=0.01,
                             precission_dtype='float32')
```

Got the client error

```
ERROR 140291262150464] Customer Error: Additional hyperparameters are not allowed (u'precission_dtype' was unexpected) (caused by ValidationError)

Caused by: Additional properties are not allowed (u'precission_dtype' was unexpected)
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this? I'm also reporting this to aws support. Posting here for sharing and get a fix. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/imageclassification_caltech/Image-classification-transfer-learning-highlevel.ipynb - you have a typo, it's `precision_dtype`, not `precission_dtype`.